# How can I send data and make commands with Binding in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show an `ImageButton` and pass it with Binding the source of the image and that when I click the button, make a command and go to a web page that I want

Im trying to do it with `MVVM` and send the data to the `ImageButton` from the `ViewModel`

MainPage.xaml:

[image]

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
namespace BindingPrueba
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```cs
namespace BindingPrueba
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        { }

        public void launcWeb(string websiteUrl)
        {
            websiteUrl = "facebook.com";
            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(websiteUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you directly copy directly MainPage.xaml's code in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the command property to your viewmodel:

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public Command OpenAppCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            OpenAppCommand = new Command(launcWeb);
        }

        public void launcWeb()
        {
            var websiteUrl = "facebook.com";
            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(websiteUrl));
        }
    }
```

If you want to pass the `CommandParameter` to the command to use your `lanchWeb(string websiteUrl)` do something like this instead:

```
  public class ViewModel
{
    public string ImageSource { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public Command<string> OpenAppCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenAppCommand = new Command<string>(launcWeb);
    }

    public void launcWeb(string websiteUrl)
    {
        websiteUrl = "facebook.com";
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(websiteUrl));
    }
}
```

The `CommandParameter` can be set from your `xaml`.

Comment: The command works in xaml with "Command" but with "CommandParameter" not.

Answer (score 0):

How about that? Instead of using an ImageButton use a Frame containing an Image with a GestureRecognizer.

```
            <Frame Style="{DynamicResource FrameButton}">
                <Image Source="{Binding SomeSource}">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CommandFromVM}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding SomeSource}"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Frame>
```

Or just use the ImageButton and use the `CommandParameter` Property

Answer (score 0):

### 0. Additional worthwhile setup

To start with I would highly recommend that you add in an `x:DataType` element to your top level `ContentPage` see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings) for further detail. This should give multiple benefits but the key one I find is the IDE is able to identify if the property you are trying to bind to actually exists.

Your example should look something like:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="cir-namespace:BindingPrueba"
             x:Class="BindingPrueba.MainPage"
             x:DataType="local:ViewModel">
```

### 1. Modify your view model to know how to notify the UI of changes

Next the key part is you will want implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that any changes in your `ViewModel` class will update the UI. [Further details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1).

### 2. Actually set your property

```
public ViewModel()
{
    ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("my path to file");
}
```

### 3. Do the same with your Command

Hopefully now if you followed step 0 then the IDE should make it clear that you don't have an `OpenAppCommand` defined on your `ViewModel`. If you add this then you should be able to trigger the action in your class.

e.g. (inside `ViewModel`)

```
public Command OpenAppCommand { get; }


public ViewModel()
{
    OpenAppCommand = new Command(() => Device.OpenUri(new Uri(this.Website)));
}
```

Note you don't strictly need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if only updating in the constructor but it is good practise to.